# Hangman Game: How To Make The Program Know I Wrote The Correct Word?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a hangman game in VB.Net and everything's going smooth except one thing.
I have a problem. Let me first explain.

You start the game, you press the button so it can generate a random word in form of "?" Then you press the keys built in the program. When you press a correct key, the "?" turns into the key you pressed. Yeah you know how hangman works.
Anyway, when i've guessed all the keys correct, i want it to tell me it was correct and randomly generate next word without pressing the "generate button"

Here's the code i wrote:

```
If Korrekt_Gissat = antal Then
       MsgBox("Nice, " & HemligaOrdet & " is correct.")
       Reset()
   End If
```

Full code:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    'Tangentbordet
    For Each ctrl In Controls
        If ctrl.tag = "Tangentbordet" Then
            ctrl.text() = Chr(90 - i)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next




    'Slumporden
    Ordlistan(0) = "Zed"
    Ordlistan(1) = "Ahri"
    Ordlistan(2) = "Udyr"
    Ordlistan(3) = "Ekko"
    Ordlistan(4) = "Shen"
    Ordlistan(5) = "Jinx"
    Ordlistan(6) = "Draven"
    Ordlistan(7) = "Thresh"
    Ordlistan(8) = "Yasuo"
    Ordlistan(9) = "Kassadin"
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSlumpa_Ord()
    Dim slumptal As Integer

    'Slumpa orden till textrutan
    slumptal = Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1)
    HemligaOrdet = Ordlistan(slumptal)
    '   TextBoxSlump.Text = HemligaOrdetu

    If HemligaOrdet = "Zed" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.Zed
    End If

    If HemligaOrdet = "Ahri" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.ahri
    End If

    If HemligaOrdet = "Udyr" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.Udyr
    End If

    If HemligaOrdet = "Ekko" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.ekko
    End If

    If HemligaOrdet = "Shen" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.shen
    End If

    If HemligaOrdet = "Jinx" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.Jinx
    End If

    If HemligaOrdet = "Draven" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.Draven
    End If

    If HemligaOrdet = "Thresh" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.Thresh
    End If

    If HemligaOrdet = "Yasuo" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.yasuo
    End If

    If HemligaOrdet = "Kassadin" Then
        PictureChampions.Image = My.Resources.Kassadin
    End If


    Skapamall()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSlumpa_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSlumpa.Click
    cmdSlumpa_Ord()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, MyBase.Click, Button9.Click, Button8.Click, Button7.Click, Button6.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button3.Click, Button29.Click, Button28.Click, Button27.Click, Button26.Click, Button25.Click, Button24.Click, Button23.Click, Button22.Click, Button21.Click, Button20.Click, Button2.Click, Button19.Click, Button18.Click, Button17.Click, Button16.Click, Button15.Click, Button14.Click, Button13.Click, Button12.Click, Button11.Click, Button10.Click
    Dim tecken As String
    Korrekt_Gissat = False

    For position = 1 To HemligaOrdet.Length
        tecken = Mid(HemligaOrdet, position, 1)
        If UCase(tecken) = sender.text Then
            Korrekt_Gissat = True
            Mid(Mallen, position, 1) = tecken
            TextBox2.Text = Mallen
        End If
    Next


    If Korrekt_Gissat = True Then
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        btn.Enabled = False
    End If

    If Korrekt_Gissat = False Then
        AntalFel = AntalFel + 1
        Bestraffa()
    End If

    If Korrekt_Gissat = antal Then
        MsgBox("Nice, " & HemligaOrdet & " is correct.")
        Reset()
    End If


    If AntalFel = 8 Then
        MsgBox("You lost!")
        End
    End If



End Sub

Private Sub Bestraffa()

    If AntalFel = 1 Then
        PicturePenality.Image = My.Resources._1
    End If

    If AntalFel = 2 Then
        PicturePenality.Image = My.Resources._2
    End If

    If AntalFel = 3 Then
        PicturePenality.Image = My.Resources._3
    End If

    If AntalFel = 4 Then
        PicturePenality.Image = My.Resources._4
    End If

    If AntalFel = 5 Then
        PicturePenality.Image = My.Resources._5
    End If

    If AntalFel = 6 Then
        PicturePenality.Image = My.Resources._6
    End If

    If AntalFel = 7 Then
        PicturePenality.Image = My.Resources._7
    End If

    If AntalFel = 8 Then
        PicturePenality.Image = My.Resources._8
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Skapamall()
    Mallen = ""
    antal = HemligaOrdet.Length
    For i = 1 To antal
        Mallen = Mallen + "?"
    Next i
    TextBox2.Text = Mallen
End Sub
End Class
```

Module:

Module Module1

```
Public Ordlistan(0 To 9) As String
Public HemligaOrdet As String
Public Mallen As String
Public antal As Integer
Public Korrekt_Gissat As Boolean
Public AntalFel As Integer

End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If Korrekt_Gissat = antal Then`
This is comparing a Boolean (Korret_Gissat) with an Integer (antal). This is usually a bad idea. Instead, check for a win in the code that checks for a correct guess. (No one could ever win on a turn with an incorrect guess, right?)

```
If Korrekt_Gissat = True Then
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    btn.Enabled = False
    If InStr(Mallen, "?") = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Congratulations, you won!")
        'any code you want to call to end or reset the game
    End If
End If
```

**Edit: Alternate Method**

Per your request below, here is another way of checking for a win. This method uses a designated function to perform the check and a `For` loop instead of `InStr`.

First, create the new function within Module1:

```
Public Function CheckForWin() As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To Mallen.Length -1
        If Mid(Mallen, i, 1) = "?" Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    'This point can only be reached if no instance of "?" was found
    Return True
End Function
```

Next, call the function from your code (where in the first version I used `InStr`).

```
If Korrekt_Gissat = True Then
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    btn.Enabled = False
    If CheckForWin() Then
        MsgBox("Congratulations, you won!")
        'any code you want to call to end or reset the game
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Whoa this worked, thanks dude. Could you just explain what InStr does and could you also show other ways to write this code, maybe easier ways for a beginner like me, if you have time :)

Comment: [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) searches the first string passed to it for instances of the second string passed to it and returns the 1-based index of the first match (0 if no match found). My method was to check you display string (Mallen) for any remaining "?" characters and know that a win has occurred if none were found. I think that's the easiest way, but since `InStr` is new to you, perhaps you'd be more comfortable using a `For` loop to check if each character in Mallen is "?".

Comment: One last question i swear, How would you use a for loop for this?, im still new to programming and would just like to learn as much as possible with many different "ways" to use the code. I know it worked but this really matters to me :P. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Srebor, see edit above. I used `Mid` because you already use that function in your code so I assume you're familiar with it. I'm always happy to help people learn beyond what this site is intended for. You may use the email listed in my profile if you have any more questions.